# I want to add my app is Deafult apps list

Tags: android, android-studio, sketchware

I want to show my app in the default app  list . For example if my App is a music player , then i want to open all files with .mp3 with my app.
I mean that i want my app to be listed in the deafult apps list for that specic extenison .[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wdvs.jpg)I want my app to come in the list of deafult lists of app. Just like this[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wdvs.jpg)

Note ..
I am new

Comment: Hey can you show us some code examples you have tried and we can try and help you from there

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare in your AndroidManifest that your app can handle these types of files. You do this with an `intent-filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This means that any time an app launches an `implicit Intent` to play an audio file, your app will show up on the list of selectable apps.